# 'gpg2' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: java, windows, maven, deployment, gnupg

I use the `maven-gpg-plugin` in linux all is okay I can install the gpg2 for sign but in windows there is a problem with deploying.

There is log `'gpg2' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` (The same I get for `gpg2 --version`)
And
`Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin:1.5:sign (sign-artifacts) on project`.

How can I install `gpg2` for windows?

Comment: Have you checked the most recent version 1.6?

Comment: @khmarbaise Do you mean maven-gpg-plugin version? I use 1.5 It's okay for linux where I have installed gpg2. But for windows I can't  find gpg2 to install

Comment: Strange, what is wrong with the installer provided at the GnuPG home page: [https://gnupg.org/download/]?

Comment: There isn't version gpg2. I have used gpg

Comment: I meant to upgrade maven-gpg-plugin..and chck if it works.

Comment: I have tried it doesn't help thanks

Comment: I had the same issue, and copied the gpg.exe and renamed it to gpg2, and it worked. Maybe not the best solution, but at least it can unblock you if needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In you settings.xml file, change the `gpg.executable` property.  Example.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>ossrh</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <gpg.executable>gpg</gpg.executable>
            <gpg.passphrase>PASSPHRASE</gpg.passphrase>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `gpg.executable` setting didn't do anything for me. What worked was:

- Run `which gpg` to locate the `gpg` executable
- Go into the directory it prints (for me it was `/usr/local/bin`)
- Make a copy of the `gpg` file in that directory and rename it to `gpg2`